# Change active slicer equal to today's date

Tags: excel, vba

I haven't seen anything that does this specifically. I have a slicer that displays dates and I would like to set it to today's date. I have a cell which also contains today's date. Is there a way for me to either 1) reference the cell to for the slicer's active value as a one-time thing (I want those using the workbook to be able to go through the days as they require). Or, 2), just set today's value to true?
I know to reference the slicer object I need

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Univ. Date")).Select
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Date")
```

For the slicer item I know it's

```
.slicerItems("1/1/1900").Selected = True
```

I know there's a lot of frustration with the use of a selected phrase; if there's a cleaner way to do it, I would love tips on that as well. Thank you for any and all assistance.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a variable cell to your VBA slicer like this, here I am assigning cell F12 of sheet 1:

```
Dim Slicer_Date As Date
Slicer_Date= Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(12, "F").Value
```

Comment: This does not work for me. There is no error to note. Thank you for your effort.